# Expressing hyperbolic functions in terms of $e$.

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

> Express $\tanh(-3)$ in terms of $e$, where $\tanh$ is the hyperbolic tangent.

This is what I did:

$$\begin{align}
\tanh(-x)&=\dfrac{e^{-2x}-1}{e^{-2x}+1}\\\\\\
\tanh(-3)&=\dfrac{e^{-2\times-3}-1}{e^{-2\times-3}+1}\\\\\\
\tanh(-3)&=\dfrac{e^6-1}{e^6+1}
\end{align}$$

However, this is wrong, as the actual solution is:

$$\tanh(-3)=-\dfrac{e^3-1}{e^3+1}$$

1. What have I done that is unacceptable, hence making my solution wrong?
2. How is the actual solution obtained? (Full explanation would be helpful)

Comment: You have too many minus signs!

Comment: I don't understand?

Comment: You plug in $-3$ into the equation of $\tanh(-x)$, which gives you $\tanh(--3) = \tanh(3)$.

Comment: You shouldn't have the $2x$s in the second line.  When you substitute in $-3$ for $x$, the $x$'s go away.

Comment: That's not an $x$, that is a multiplication sign $\times$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the definition $$\tanh(x) = \frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}$$So we plug in $-3$ wherever we see an $x$ to get that $$\tanh(-3) = \frac{e^{2 \cdot-3}-1}{e^{2\cdot-3}+1}=\frac{e^{-6}-1}{e^{-6}+1} $$So we multiply by $\frac{e^6}{e^6}$ to get $$= \frac{1-e^6}{1 + e^6}$$So other than a little minus sign error, I think you're correct!

Comment: Okay, but the definition I used for $tanh(-x)$ is the correct definition, in which case, surely I haven't done I minus sign error? Let me know where I'm going wrong with this statement please thanks for the answer as well

Answer (score 1):

Your first attept is really right. In fact, you got $$\tanh(-3)=-\frac{e^3-e^{-3}}{e^3+e^{-3}}=-\frac{e^3-\frac{1}{e^{3}}}{e^3+\frac{1}{e^{-3}}}=-\frac{e^6-1}{e^6+1}$$ Knowing that $\tanh(x)$is an odd function also, the actual solution you pointed doesn't seem right result.

Comment: **Sign error!!**

Comment: @andybenji: Where??

Comment: numerator should be $e^{-3} - e^3$.

Comment: @andybenji: Thanks andy, but I have a minus before the fraction. And both of us noted the same ting at last. Didn't we?